# is it possible to do a segmentation with k-means clustering in CIELAB color space of a 3d grey scale array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, k-means

I have a 3d array (grayscale) and I would like to do segmentation.
I am using Matlab for this and I found this documentation: https://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/color-based-segmentation-using-k-means-clustering.html

However, this is for a 2D RGB image, so I was wondering if there is a way to do this for a 3D array in grayscale, so clustering based on intensity instead of colors.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = load('mri.mat');
D = squeeze(d.D);
numClusters = 3;
out = imsegkmeans3(D,numClusters);
figure
labelvolshow(out)
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about imsegkmeans3. I modified the code a bit and it works great!